# Scrapy Csv export has all extracted data in one cell

Tags: scrapy

I am currently building my first scrapy project. Currently I am trying to extract data from a HTML table. Here is my crawl spider so far:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from digikey.items import DigikeyItem
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class DigikeySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'digikey'
    allowed_domains = ['digikey.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.digikey.com/products/en/capacitors/aluminum-electrolytic-capacitors/58/page/3?stock=1']
    ['www.digikey.com/products/en/capacitors/aluminum-electrolytic-capacitors/58/page/4?stock=1']

    rules = (
        # Extract links matching 'category.php' (but not matching 'subsection.php')
        # and follow links from them (since no callback means follow=True by default).
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/products/en/capacitors/aluminum-electrolytic-capacitors/58/page/3?stock=1', ), deny=('subsection\.php', ))),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = DigikeyItem()
        item['partnumber'] = response.xpath('//td[@class="tr-mfgPartNumber"]/a/span[@itemprop="name"]/text()').extract()
        item['manufacturer'] =  response.xpath('///td[6]/span/a/span/text()').extract()
        item['description'] = response.xpath('//td[@class="tr-description"]/text()').extract()
        item['quanity'] = response.xpath('//td[@class="tr-qtyAvailable ptable-param"]//text()').extract()
        item['price'] = response.xpath('//td[@class="tr-unitPrice ptable-param"]/text()').extract()
        item['minimumquanity'] = response.xpath('//td[@class="tr-minQty ptable-param"]/text()').extract()
        yield item

    parse_start_url = parse_item
```

It scrapes the table at `www.digikey.com/products/en/capacitors/aluminum-electrolytic-capacitors/58/page/4?stock=1`. It then exports all data to a `digikey.csv` file but all data is in one cell.
[Csv file with scraped data in one cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajUJd.png)

setting.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'digikey'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['digikey.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'digikey.spiders'


# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
USER_AGENT = 'digikey ("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36")'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
```

I want the information scraped with one line at a time with the corresponding information associated with that partnumber.

items.py

```
import scrapy


class DigikeyItem(scrapy.Item):
    partnumber = scrapy.Field()
    manufacturer = scrapy.Field()
    description = scrapy.Field()
    quanity= scrapy.Field()
    minimumquanity = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're loading into each field of a single item the whole columns. I feel that what you want is something like:

```
for row in response.css('table#productTable tbody tr'):
    item = DigikeyItem()
    item['partnumber'] = (row.css('.tr-mfgPartNumber [itemprop="name"]::text').extract_first() or '').strip()
    item['manufacturer'] =  (row.css('[itemprop="manufacture"] [itemprop="name"]::text').extract_first() or '').strip()
    item['description'] = (row.css('.tr-description::text').extract_first() or '').strip()
    item['quanity'] = (row.css('.tr-qtyAvailable::text').extract_first() or '').strip()
    item['price'] = (row.css('.tr-unitPrice::text').extract_first() or '').strip()
    item['minimumquanity'] = (row.css('.tr-minQty::text').extract_first() or '').strip()
    yield item
```

I've changed a bit the selectors to try to make it shorter. btw please avoid the manual `extract_first` and `strip` repetitions that I've used here (just for testing purposes), and consider using [Item Loaders](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html), it should be easier to take the first and strip/format the desired output.